# BitMap Eventlistener not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener to my BitMap. Tile extends gameProps, which extends BitMap. I try using addEventListener. That doesnt work. but the Adobe docs say that Bitmap has an addEventListener object.

```
 package {
            import flash.display.BitmapData;
            import flash.events.*;
            import flash.events.MouseEvent;
            import flash.geom.Rectangle;
            import flash.geom.Point;

            public class Tile extends gameProps {

                public var tileNum:Number = 0;


                public function Tile(tileNumber:Number):void
                {
                    tileNum = tileNumber;           
                    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, respond);
                }


                public function respond(e:MouseEvent):void
                {   trace("HELLO");             
                }

            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bitmap class extends the DisplayObject not the InteractiveObject and can therefore not receive mouse events. Try wrapping the bitmap object in a Sprite sub-class. Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
public class Image extends Sprite
{
     var bitmap:Bitmap;

     public function Image()
     {
         bitmap = new Bitmap();
         addChild( bitmap );
     }
}
```

InteractiveObject Docs: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html

Comment: O, I was looking at the docs and it said it inherited EventDispatcher, so plus it showed one its methods being addEventlistner. Not sure why. But I am trying to be light as possible. I am tiling and using sprites slow down my scrolling. is there a better solution ?

Comment: @numerical25: Keep reading the documentation, and you'll see that just because something is an EventDispatcher, doesn't mean that it reacts to mouse events. All display objects are event dispatchers, to be able to dispatch events such as ADDED_TO_STAGE and REMOVED_FROM STAGE.

Comment: yea but it also showed addeventlistner as a method
 http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Bitmap.html . not saying that you guys are wrong. I completely agree. but it just threw me off a little. but thanks for your help. I appreciate it alot.

Comment: Just because something has a method called addEventListener(), doesn't mean that you can add mouse listeners to it. Think of the SoundChannel object that plays back audio. It's not possible to directly click a sound, though you can add event listeners to it. There are three event types you can listen for on a SoundChannel object: ACTIVATE, DEACTIVATE & SOUND_COMPLETE. You can add listeners for these three event types because the SoundChannel object dispatches them. The Bitmap class doesn't dispatch any mouse events. It dispatches other events, those inherited from it's super-class. helpful?